# Maximum of subordinated norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-norms

```
Hello i'm currently trying to find this :
```

> Let $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\| \ \|_{\infty}$ be the uniform norm over $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as,
> $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|(x,y)\|_{\infty}=\max_{\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, \| (x,y)\|_{\infty} \leq 1  \}}(|x|,|y|). $

> Find $\|f\|$.

What i did is :

Since $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then $\exists a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^2, f(v)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$.

We have to find $\|f\|=\max_{\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, \| (x,y)\|_{\infty} \leq 1  \}} \|f(x,y)\|_{\infty} $

I noted that,
\begin{align}\max_{\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, \| (x,y)\|_{\infty} \leq 1  \}} \|f(x,y)\|_{\infty} &=\max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} \|f(x,y)\|_{\infty} \\ &=\max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} \|f(x,y)\|_{\infty} \\&=\max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1}( \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} (|ax+by|,|cx+dy|)) 
\end{align}

Now $|ax+by| \leq |a||x]+|b||y|\leq |a| + |b|$ is an upper bound and is atteined for $|a|=a* sign(a), |b|=b*sign(b)$ so it is the maximum of $|ax+by|$ over $  \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ such that }|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1 \}$.

So we have $ \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} (|ax+by|,|cx+dy|))=|a|+|b| $ or $|c|+|d|$.

Now suppose  $ \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} (|ax+by|,|cx+dy|))=|a|+|b| $

Then we have,
\begin{align}
 \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1}( \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} (|ax+by|,|cx+dy|)) = \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1}(|a|+|b|,|cx+dy|)
\end{align}

and it is here that i'm not sure the second max gives what i've just written.

If it is it is easy to conclude by setting $x=sign(c)$ and $y=sign(d)$ so we have
$|cx+dy|=|(c*sign(c)+d*sign(d))|=|(|c|+|d|)|=|c|+|d| \leq |a|+|b|$.

We do the same for $ \max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1} (|ax+by|,|cx+dy|))=|c|+|d| $

And we conclude that $ \| f\|=\max_{|x| \leq 1 \text{ and } |y| \leq 1}(|a|+|b|,|c|+|d|)$

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is bad. It is so bad that trying to straighten it out over this forum is not practicable. You have mashed up the definitions, making them non-sensical, and clearly do not understand the notations and concepts behind them. You need to back up, study the basics again, and drill yourself on them before returning to this problem. I suggest a frank discussion with your professor, who hopefully has a better understanding of where you are and what you need to do.